# Postgres many to many: how to select record with exactly counted links

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, aggregate, has-and-belongs-to-many

With that schema (there's more fields, sure) I wonder to select exactly chats where clients.id are for example 344,345 and they are exactly two.

But I find all chats where they are with others clients, not only they two.

[image: Schema]
<sub>(source: [zimagez.com](http://www.zimagez.com/miniature/107410861087108810861089-10871086-habtm0.png))</sub>

Big picture http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/107410861087108810861089-10871086-habtm0.php

```
SELECT 
  chat_rooms.id, 
  chat_rooms.token
FROM 
  chat_rooms, 
  clients, 
  chat_rooms_clients
WHERE 
  chat_rooms_clients.chat_room_id = chat_rooms.id AND
  chat_rooms_clients.client_id = clients.id AND
  clients.id IN (344,354) AND 
  chat_rooms.meeting_id IS NULL
group by chat_rooms.id
having count(clients.id) = 2
ORDER BY
  chat_rooms.created_at DESC;
```

My app is written with rails.

Comment: What relationship in your schema represents two clients talking to each other?

Comment: Pardon, did not get what you ask.

Comment: This is my feeling exactly, I did not get what you ask.  Can you elaborate on what constitutes a relationship between two clients?

Comment: More complicated part of full schema.

http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/107410861087108810861089-10871086-habtm1.php

This part of DB is for storing history and preventing unauthorized access. Real communication is going through rabbitmq->stomp->websockets.

**chat_room is a chat**.

I have chat_rooms with for ex. 3 clients - those, 344, 354 and 355, or chat_room with 344, 890, or where chat_room.clients.ids are 354, 700 and so on. And I want to find exactly chat_room where only those two clients are present. Excuse me my wooden english.

Comment: > what constitutes a relationship between two clients. <
chat_room is the relationship, isnt it?
I want to find a room, that is addressed by only two records in chat_rooms_clients table, and those two records must link exactly those clients I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the supplied test data:

```
set search_path = testschema, pg_catalog;
select cr.id, array_agg(crc.client_id order by crc.client_id), cr.token
from
    chat_rooms_clients crc
    inner join
    chat_rooms cr on cr.id = crc.chat_room_id
where cr.meeting_id is null
group by 1
having array_agg(crc.client_id order by crc.client_id) = array[2467,2471]::int[]
order by cr.created_at desc;
 id  |  array_agg  |                token
-----+-------------+--------------------------------------
 234 | {2467,2471} | bd36db10-3a89-40fe-a3e3-524b4278b718
```

Notice that for this query it is not necessary to join the `clients` table. I think it is wise to create a primary key in the `chat_rooms_clients` table:

```
create table chat_rooms_clients (
    chat_room_id integer not null,
    client_id integer not null,
    primary key (chat_room_id, client_id)
);
```

Otherwise, to be on the safe side, it is necessary to add `distinct` in the `array_agg` in the above query:

```
having array_agg(distinct crc.client_id order by crc.client_id) = ...
```

If the chat room creator must be one of the chat participants then filter it to improve performance:

```
where cr.meeting_id is null and cr.creator_id in (2467,2471)
```

Comment: Your desicion finds two chats: one what I need, and another with 3 clients linked.

If you are interested, I can share full example with rspec and model methods.

For that case it seems a denormalisation like storing foreign keys in array in chat_room record is simpler to use.

Comment: @Dimitri Post sample data with all the clients my query returns

Comment: @Dimitri Do not test it from Rails. Test it from a Posgresql client.

Comment: Okay. Full dump of the test base, for user testuser.
https://yadi.sk/d/7M8yhskwy4aE2
5 clients c0-c4 #2467-#2471
5 chat_rooms: #232(c2,c1) meeting_id 277, #233(c2,c1) meeting_id null, #234(c0,c4), #235(c0,c3,c4), #236(c1,c2,c4).
So the request must find for example #233, but not 236, or #235, but not #234 and vice versa.
Now it finds #236, #233.

Comment: @Dimitri Updated with the supplied test data

Comment: Big work! Thank you a lot. Yes, creator_id is one of users in chat. And now I need to translate that to rails bird's language :)